# Why does COUNT(*) multiply the results when there are several tables?

Tags: sql

I've got this:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    TABLE1,
    TABLE2,
    TABLE3;
```

Say TABLE1 has 5 entries, TABLE2 has 5 entries, and TABLE3 has one, COUNT(*) essentially becomes 5*5*1 = 25. Is there a reason for this? Ideally, I want the total rowcount from all 3 tables WITHOUT having to use multiple from statements.

Comment: Look up the definition of CROSS JOIN

Comment: look at what `select * from table1, table2, table3` does

Comment: Because you are doing a Cartesian Join between all three of the tables, resulting in every possible combination of values between the three.

Comment: @Siyual This comment should be an answer. :)

Comment: Why do you need only one `FROM`? I think trying to achieve that doesn't have much sense. You should simply want the clearest and fastest code.

Comment: I'm currently dealing with SQL using String manipulation in Java. Being able to just use a StringBuilder to delete everything between SELECT and FROM and replace it with a COUNT(*) would be much easier than having to create multiple sub-queries. Especially since the queries I'm getting can be as simple as a single SELECT-FROM statement to much more complex queries.

Comment: @TheFaster That would be simpler if it worked that way, but it doesn't.  The syntax isn't doing what you're thinking it's doing.  You will need to use sub-queries to get the results you're looking for.

Comment: Well, I knew it wasn't doing what I hoped it was doing. I was hoping there was a simple workaround, but it would seem that's not the case. I'm thinking now the simplest course of action would be to delete the entire SQL String except for the FROM statements, and then wrap each FROM statement in an individual sub-query. Thanks for the help,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    TABLE1,
    TABLE2,
    TABLE3;
```

does a `CROSS JOIN`.  It matches each record in `TABLE1` with each record in `TABLE2`, then matches eash result with each record in `TABLE3`, so for example if `TABLE1` contained 2 records, `TABLE2` contained 3 records and `TABLE4` contained 4 records, you'd get `2 X 3 X 4 = 24` as your result.

To get the counts from each table you'll need to use subqueries:

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE1),
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE2),
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE3);
```

OR

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE1
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE2
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE3
```

to get the result as records instead of columns

Comment: I wonder if his request *"I want the total rowcount from all 3 tables WITHOUT having to use multiple from statements"* can be done without some strange TSQL code.

Comment: check my answer, maybe can help you.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is you are making join 's (cross join) , is about the set theory from the school , if you want count 3 different tables and then  sum that counts together , you can do this:

```
SELECT
SUM(COUNT)
FROM 
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNT FROM TABLE1
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNT FROM TABLE2
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNT FROM TABLE3
) TB
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically your count is counting every result. Your select is finding:

```
table1result1 table2result1 table3result1
table1result1 table2result2 table3result1
table1result1 table2result3 table3result1
table1result1 table2result4 table3result1
table1result1 table2result5 table3result1
table1result2 table2result1 table3result1
table1result2 table2result2 table3result1
table1result2 table2result3 table3result1
table1result2 table2result4 table3result1
table1result2 table2result5 table3result1
table1result3 table2result1 table3result1
table1result3 table2result2 table3result1
table1result3 table2result3 table3result1
table1result3 table2result4 table3result1
table1result3 table2result5 table3result1
table1result4 table2result1 table3result1
table1result4 table2result2 table3result1
table1result4 table2result3 table3result1
table1result4 table2result4 table3result1
table1result4 table2result5 table3result1
table1result5 table2result1 table3result1
table1result5 table2result2 table3result1
table1result5 table2result3 table3result1
table1result5 table2result4 table3result1
table1result5 table2result5 table3result1
```

which if you count is 25 results. The reason being, as Siyual said in the comments, your joins. When you set up a join without any sort of condition to limit the results it returns, it will return every possible combination of records between the joined tables, because you didn't tell it not to.

Comment: this post, has an explanation with preview data, but don't have the solution of his issue.

Comment: His question was "Is there a reason for this?" Which is what I set out to answer.

Comment: and then he say: "Ideally, I want the total rowcount from all 3 tables", just a comment.

Comment: True, but this question sort of reeks of homework. So I figured I'd explain the whys. And let him figure out the hows.

Comment: you right, It was my wrong i think, thank you for the response.